# Alternatives to Subtotal function in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have 36,892 records that I need to subtotal. When I use the subtotal function in excel it can't cope with the amount of data and crashes.

I have 36,000 rows of data and I need to add the data in column d for every change in column a. The number of duplicate records in column a changes anywhere from 1 to 10.

I have tried breaking it into smaller chunks of data, but it only seems to cope with about 5,000 which is going to take forever.

Is there another alternative I can use?

Comment: Why subtotal and not sum or sumifs? Filtered data? Hidden rows? Aggregate is the newer alternative to subtotal.

Comment: I'm not sure how I could implement summits or filters in this instance? Don't know what you mean by hidden rows or aggregate? I have 36,000 rows of data and I need to add the data in column d for every change in column a. The number of duplicate records in column a changes anywhere from 1 to 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an unused column to the right put this formula in the second row and [double-click the fill handle](https://superuser.com/questions/859501/fill-formulas-until-end-of-adjacent-table/859580#859580).

```
if(a2<>a3, sumifs(d:d, a:a, a2), text(,))
```